# Integrate semantic-ui-react and material-ui in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, semantic-ui

I have a plan integration of semantic-ui-react [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-react) and material-ui [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core) together in react project. Before that i do research about good and bad things when use both semantic-ui-react and material-ui together in one project. But There is no luck. Any help would be appreciated provide with resources link?

Comment: It's always depence upon your use mean for which task you use material or ui-react.

Comment: why you want to use both ? just take one they do the same things behind the scene it's just a Front-End Frameworks who allows you to have pre-made components